# Automapper custom mapping issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, automapper, automapper-6

I am first time user of Automapper using version 6.2.2. I am try to find out how can I map below DB entity to custom DTO.

```
public partial class vw_Owner
{
    public int Space_Id { get; set; }       
    public string Owner_ID { get; set; }
    public string Owner_SID { get; set; }
    public string Owner_Name { get; set; }
}

public class OwnerDTO
{        
    public int SpaceId { get; set; }        
    public string OwnerID { get; set; }
    public string OwnerSID { get; set; }
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my mapping profile.

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public static readonly IMapper iMapperConfig;
    static MappingProfile()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            //cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
            //cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
            //cfg.AddMemberConfiguration().AddName<ReplaceName>(_ => _.AddReplace("_", ""));               

            cfg.CreateMap<vw_Owner, Owner>();                
        });
        iMapperConfig = config.CreateMapper();            
    }
}
```

I also tried to create my own custom naming convention. Below is code, but it is not working.

```
public class UnderscoreNamingConvention : INamingConvention
{
    public Regex SplittingExpression { get; } = new Regex(@"[\p{Lu}\p{Ll}0-9]+(?=_?)");

    public string SeparatorCharacter => "_";

    //public string ReplaceValue(Match match) => match.Value;//.ToLower();
    public string ReplaceValue(Match match)
    {
        return match.Value;
    }
}
```

I tried commented lines from documentation, but doesn't seems to work. I have 15+ similar database entities containing _ but DTO classes doesn't. I am looking for a way to fix for all entities with some resolver.

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html?highlight=LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention#naming-conventions

Comment: I have tried above but it doesn't seems to work because my source property is not in lower case like owner_id. It is pascal case Owner_ID.

Comment: You'll have to customize the naming convention to do what you want.

Comment: how do I do that, can you point to some example?

Comment: It's just a regular expression. You have to change that to suit your needs.

Comment: Have you initialised your mapping profile? Can't see from your code provided.